# How to format text within a p tag using PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I've seen many question which are almost what I am looking to do and have led me to almost be able to get it but not quite.

I want to format text as follows within a `<p>` tag which is within a div.

> Page **1** of 2

So in ordinary HTML I used the b tag within the paragraph but can't seem to figure out how to do that with DomDocument.  When I try to create an element like so

```
$pTag = $dom->createElement("p", "Page <b>1</b> of 2");
```

It outputs just that without recognising the  as HTML.  So I thought about it and came up with

```
$pTag->nodeValue .=
```

as a way to append a new element but that did no good.  It didn't give me any errors but it didn't append the `<b>` tag either.  This seems like something that should be simple but doesn't seem to be.

When I tried `echo` it outputted the text to the top of the screen, not where I wanted it.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: You need to provide more details for what exactly you are trying to do. If you just want to `output text`, you can just `echo '<p>Page <b>1</b> of 2</p>';`. Tell us more.

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode

Comment: I edited to try to clarify what I am doing.  @DerekOrgan I hadn't seen that question even though I've been searching for hours.  Apologies if this is a duplicate but tbh I don't think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
$bTag = $dom->createElement("b", "1");
$pTag = $dom->createElement("p");
$pTag->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("Page "));
$pTag->appendChild($bTag);
$pTag->appendChild($dom->createTextNode(" of 2"));
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.