# PHP how can I append $html_div (string type) to child of DOMElement

Tags: php, html, string, document

**MY ENGLISH IS NOT GOOD  :"))  PLEASE HELP ME THAT**

```
 <?php

        $htmldiv= //it is html ,and it is not XML.
            "<div class=\"MyClass\" id=\"MyID\">
                ABC <hr> 
                <div></div>
            </div>";
        $html=
            "<!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <title>TEST</title>
            </head>

            <body></body>
            </html>";

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $elementlist = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body");
        $body=$elementlist->item(0);


        $body->appendChild( $htmldiv ); // it is error. i want to append $htmldiv into $body and how can i do ????? :'(


        echo $dom->saveHTML();

    ?>
```

**I CAN NOT USE createDocumentFragment . HOW can i do??**

```
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($htmldiv);
$body->appendChild( $fragment ); // it is error.
```

Comment: `it is error` is not a proper problem description. The exact error message (pasted here via clipboard) is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert HTML to PHP DOMNode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use PHP's [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and do it easily (just like jQuery)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>TEST</title></head><body></body></html>");
$html->find('body', 0)->innertext = "<div class='MyClass' id='MyID'>ABC<hr><div></div></div>";
echo $html;
```

It's a small library to make the dom manipulation easy and it really did it, you can use it easily, it's a fun.