# Insert HTML into div tag with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put $htmlString into an existing div tag that I have

```
<?php
    $htmlString = "<ul><li>some items</li><li>some items</li><li>some items</li></ul>";
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $div_tag = $dom->getElementById('demo');
    echo $dom->saveHTML($div_tag);
?>
```

In the div tag, I already have some content and I want to append $htmlString into the div tag

```
<div id="demo"><h1>Recent Posts</h1></div>
```

I want the output to be

```
<div id="demo"><h1>Recent Posts</h1>
<ul><li>some items</li><li>some items</li><li>some items</li></ul>
</div>
```

As $htmlString is actually produced from another function so I cannot simply do

```
<div id="demo">
<h1>Recent Posts</h1>
    <?php echo "<ul><li>some items</li><li>some items</li><li>some items</li></ul>" ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `$dom->appendChild($div_tag)`

Comment: Can't you do this with Ajax?

Comment: @Akintunde How can I do this with Ajax?

Comment: Akintunde what has AJAX got to do with anything? This is a PHP question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice and easy, you need a fragment!

```
<?php

$html = '<div id="demo"><h1>Recent Posts</h1></div>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0); // your div to append to

$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<ul><li>some items</li><li>some items</li><li>some items</li></ul>');

$node->appendChild($fragment);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Which will give you your desired output. Check it out here https://3v4l.org/JrJan

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php][1]

[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php, but you need to create all structure for $htmlString. Or you can do like in this answer [How to insert HTML to PHP DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode)