# Adding HTML containing a <script> tag to a PHP DOM element sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: php, dom

I used this solution to add HTML to a DOM element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401089/7422578

```php
  function appendHTML(DOMNode $parent, $source) {
        $tmpDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmpDoc->loadHTML($source);
        foreach ($tmpDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
            $node = $parent->ownerDocument->importNode($node, true);
            $parent->appendChild($node);
        }
    }

    $elem = $dom->createElement('div');
    appendHTML($elem, '<h1>Hello world</h1>');
```

I have code that adds HTML after paragraphs in the WordPress post content (using https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php library that extends the native DOMDocument):

```php
  private function appendHTML($parent, $source) {
        $tmpDoc = new HTML5DOMDocument();
        try {
            $tmpDoc->loadHTML($source);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e);
        }
        $nodes = $tmpDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $node = $parent->ownerDocument->importNode($node, true);
            $parent->appendChild($node);
        }
    }


    public function insert($content, $insertion, $paragraphNumber) {
        $dom = new HTML5DOMDocument;
        try {
            $dom->loadHTML("<div id='pwrap'>{$content}</div>");
            $paragraphsCount = $this->dom->querySelectorAll('#pwrap > p')->count();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e);
        }

        if ($paragraphsCount <= $paragraphNumber) {
            return $content;
        }

        $element = $dom->createElement('div');
        $this->appendHTML($element, $insertion);

        $target = $dom->querySelectorAll('#pwrap > p')->item($paragraphNumber - 1);
        if ( !is_null($target)) {
            $target->parentNode->insertBefore($element, $target->nextSibling);
        } else {
            return $content;
        }

        return $dom->querySelector('#pwrap')->innerHTML;
    }
```

And it works, but the problem comes when I want to add HTML that contains a `<script>` tag. When the same page is refreshed, sometimes my added element shows up and sometimes it doesn't.

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

Comment: Your code looks overall correct, so for debugging sake, temporarily remove all `try/catch` stuff and make sure that PHP error reporting is turned on completely. Then, for all of your `if` statements, if they are "should never happen but just in case", remove those and set them to fatal errors. See if that makes anything jump up. If not, you'll probably have to start throwing some `var_dump` around at the start and end of things, and inside loops to see.

Comment: @ChrisHaas 
I checked the content of `$element` with this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087136/7422578
Just before adding the element after the paragraph, I added the following code: `var_dump($this->DOMinnerHTML($element));`. And the HTML I want to add is in it even when my element is not showing up. So it looks like there is a problem with this line of code: `$target->parentNode->insertBefore($element, $target->nextSibling);`
I have no idea why there are problems with this when HTML contains `<script>`. I checked everything.