# How to add text node in new created element with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

How can I add content to the newly created tag? For example, I need to create like the following tag:

```js
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/">
    alert("ok");
</script>
```

I have implemented the following code:

```php
$finalDom = new DOMDocument;
$finalDom->loadHTML("", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);


$newElement = $finalDom->createElement("script");
$newElement->setAttribute("src", "https://stackoverflow.com/");

$finalDom->appendChild($newElement);
```

The result of this code is an only empty script tag:

```js
<script src="https://stackoverflow.com/"></script>
```

Comment: You can reference to this example as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode

Comment: Look into you request, I think someone already asked before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the content using [$textContent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) property of [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement).

```
$newElement = $finalDom->createElement("script");
$newElement->setAttribute("src", "https://stackoverflow.com/");

$newElement->textContent = 'alert("ok");';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [createTextNode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) to add text node for the element, as

```
....
$newElement->setAttribute("src", "https://stackoverflow.com/");
$finalDom->appendChild($newElement);
$newElement->appendChild($finalDom->createTextNode('your text here'));
....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of these three options for adding text

```
elem.append(document.createTextNode(text))
elem.innerHTML = text
elem.textContent = text
```

Comment: Are you answering in the context of javascript? This is a php question.

Comment: this is a PHP question