# php DOMDocument append element as html not text

Tags: php

the Following code will append html to element id main

I want to append content as html but it appended as text

```
       $html='<div id="main"></div>';
       $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
       $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' .$html);
       $el = $doc->getElementById('main');
       $appended = $doc->createElement('div', '<div><h1> Hello world</h1></div>');
       $el->appendChild($appended);
       echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

current out

<h1> Hello world</h1>

but I want

**Hello world**

Comment: so `$appended->appendChild($doc->createElement('h1', 'Hello World'));` ?

Comment: @Jakumi , No, that is simple example , I want the general way to append html to element

Comment: @Jakumi has pointed you in the right direction. alternatively you could "just" plop it in innerHtml - but it is not foolproof, and you should sanitize to avoid XSS

Comment: @JoSSte if I want to add more code like <div><h1> Hello world</h1><b>test</b><hr></div> ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert HTML to PHP DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode)

Comment: When adding an element, the second parameter will be escaped and so show the text as literal text.

Comment: The isssue is your output. Its not applying the formatting rules. Wherever you output this you must use raw html (For twig it would be `|raw`)